# C# Run command on command prompt and show the command

Tags: c#, cmd, command

I am trying to create an app that starts cmd.exe and send command. It is important that the command is visible on cmd. Here is that I got so far but it doesn't seem to be working. Any idea?

```
            Process myProc = new Process();
            myProc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            myProc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            myProc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            myProc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            myProc.Start();
            StreamWriter sendCommand = myProc.StandardInput;
            sendCommand.WriteLine("run.exe --forever"); //I want this command to show up in cmd
```

When the code above is executed, run.exe is ran but the command does not show up in cmd.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're probably not seeing it because you've redirected standard output.  Try commenting that out and see what happens.

Comment: Can't run StandardInput without Redirection.

Comment: Not input output.  The output of the child process is redirected back to the calling process but you're not doing anything with.  You don't need to redirect both streams just to use the input stream.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an addendum to my comment to make it clearer:

```
Process myProc = new Process();
myProc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
myProc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
//myProc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
myProc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
myProc.Start();
System.IO.StreamWriter sendCommand = myProc.StandardInput;
sendCommand.WriteLine("run.exe --forever");
```

This will allow everything outputted by `cmd` to show in the `cmd` console.

Answer (score 0):

why you are using the streamwriter ?
you can use the Arguments

```
 myProc.StartInfo.Arguments="run.exe --forever";
```